# Why is Windows Authentication behaving differently when my web API is deployed?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application, windows-authentication

I have three SPA built with AngularJS that are making requests to a ASP.NET Web API. I have had a lot of trouble configuring the web API to work with Windows Authentication together with CORS but I have finally managed to do it.

I have a controller in my web API that returns the username of the current logged in Windows user by accessing `User.Identity.Name`, which works absolutely fine in localhost and returns the name of the current Windows user. My SPA makes a GET request for .../api/users and gets the name of the user, which is then displayed on the navigation bar.

I also need the username because I have to check if it is in the users table of the database that I am using and if so, check what permissions and roles he has. This table was made by me and is not to be confused with one of the Windows Identity tables, which I am not using.

My problem is that, when I try the same thing after deploying the web API to a live server `User.Identity.Name` doesn't seem to be working. When my SPA send a GET request to .../api/users I get this error:

> {"message":"an error has occurred"}

I cannot have visual studio installed on the production server because of company policies so I cannot debug what is happening. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Do they have windows authentication enabled in IIS on the live server where you are hosting the Web API?

Comment: @Dylan Yes, they do.